# Crop only -2 standard deviation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, jupyter-notebook

in the following Histogram there are parts that are below 0 and a peak just after 0 , I wanted to remove them so I thought I'd remove 2std of the database but the code seems to cut 2std at the end and the start.

Thank you.

```
import pandas as pd
import random as r
import numpy as np


 df = pd.read_csv('D:\\Project\\database\\3-Last\\LastCombineHalf.csv')
df[df.apply(lambda x :(x-x.mean()).abs()<(2*x.std()) ).all(1)]
df.to_csv('D:\\Project\\database\\3-Last\\Removal.csv', index=False)
```

[image]

Comment: I provided answer below, but now I am thinking you are looking to remove part of the spike at the bottom of the histogram by finding the peaks std_dev and mean, etc.  That is a different question than I answered.

Comment: Do you have a [mcve]? In light of the comment by @merit_2, can you clarify what the issue/question is?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

get standard deviation of a column using [.std()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.std.html)

```
dev=df['col_name'].std()
```

then filtering the data you are plotting in the histogram,

```
df[df['hist_data']>=2*dev]
```

though in a spectrum like this I'd set a LLD (Lower Level Discrimator) and just cut it out, similar to above.

Like this,

```
filtered_data = df[df['hist_data']>=0]
```

Comment: I'm sorry from what I understand this will edit how the histogram is plotted, but I meant what if I want to edit the database itself, then I plot the histogram? Sorry if that is what you meat by your answer.